# Showing just the pages in a segment when using biblatex and backref=true

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

I'm using [`biblatex`](http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) to manage bibliographies, and the `backref=true` option to:

> print back references in the bibliography. The back references are
>   a list of page numbers indicating the pages on which the respective bibliography
>   entry is cited

I'm writing a document with several chapters using the `report` class. The content of each chapter is put in a `refsegment` environment and `\printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]` is used at the end of it to show the corresponding references list. Besides that, at the end of the document, the global bibliography (which includes the references cited in all the chapters) is printed with `\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]`.

As a result, the `(cit. on pp. <page>, <page>...)` is the same with all the `\printbibliography` calls. If a reference is cited in chapter 1 and 2, both pages `(cit. on pp. <pageinch1>, <pageinch2>)` will appear in the partial lists of chapter 1 and chapter 2, and in the global list (see MWE below).

How can I make `biblatex` show only the pages corresponding to a `refsegment` in the references list when the `[heading=subbibliography]` option is used to print it? I'd like to have the behaviour of a `refsection` for the `backrefs` in each chapter, but that of a `refsegment` for the entries so that all the references are printed at the end.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,10pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic,natbib=true,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IEEEfull.bib}
\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

 \chapter{Introduction}
  \begin{refsegment}
   \cite{IEEEexample:articledualmonths}
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsegment}

 \chapter{Second chapter}
  \begin{refsegment}
   \cite{IEEEexample:articledualmonths}
   \cite{IEEEexample:IEEEwebsite}
   \nocite{IEEEexample:book_typical,IEEEexample:article_typical}  
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsegment}

\cleardoublepage
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]

\end{document}
```