# Grouping pages in chapters when using biblatex and backref=true

Tags: biblatex, formatting, back-referencing

I have used `etoolbox` to reset the page counter in each non-starred chapter, and I've changed `\thepage` to print both the chapter number and the page number:

```
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}
```

Besides that I'm using `biblatex` to print partial (in a chapter, if wanted) and global bibliographies (as a `chapter*` at the end). When a reference is cited in several pages of a chapter and in different chapters the `backref` option prints quite an ugly result, because of the chosen page numbering format (see MWE). I'd like to:

1. Make `biblatex` group the pages into chapters in the backrefs when the `[heading=bibliography]` option is used to print it.
2. Make `biblatex` show just the list pages (without the chapter number) in the backref, when then `[heading=subbibliography]` option is used to print it.

In the MWE the backref of `[ODO95]` we show the following backrefs:

- In `page I`: `[cit. on chapters 1 (pp. 1, 3), 2 (p. 1)]`
- In `page 1-3`: `[cit. on pp. 1, 3]`;
- In `page 2-1`: `[cit. on p. 1]`.

When a citation is made out of any chapter, the backref in the global bibliography should show the pages too. Say we uncomment the three lines after `\begin{document}` in the MWE, the backref in `page I` would be `[cit. on chapters 1 (pp. 1, 3), 2 (p. 1); and page i]`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,10pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic,natbib=true,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IEEEfull.bib}
\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

%\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\roman{page}}
%\cite{IEEEexample:articledualmonths}
%\clearpage
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}

 \chapter{Introduction}
  \begin{refsegment}
   \cite{IEEEexample:articledualmonths} \lipsum[1-10] \cite{IEEEexample:articledualmonths}
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsegment}

 \chapter{Second chapter}
  \begin{refsegment}
   \cite{IEEEexample:articledualmonths}
   \cite{IEEEexample:IEEEwebsite}
   \nocite{IEEEexample:book_typical,IEEEexample:article_typical}  
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsegment}

\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\Roman{page}}
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]

\end{document}
```

---

I've read some questions about formatting the backrefs with `biblatex` [[a](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36307/formatting-back-references-in-bibliography), [b](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/149009/biblatex-pagebackref-reference-in-the-flush-right-margin)], but they don't target changing the "content" of the list, just the format. However, I took one of those answers as a reference to achieve this format:

```
\newbibmacro*{pageref}{\iflistundef{pageref}{}
 {\finentrypunct\addspace\renewcommand\finentrypunct{}%
  \printtext[parens]{%
   \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}%
    {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}%
    {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
   \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}}
```

I believe that the content is shown with `\printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}`. I read about it and about `\DeclareListFormat` in the documentation of `biblatex`. I feel that I should declare a new list format, but I don't how to do it, neither how the content is fed into `pageref` or read from it.

---

I asked another [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203768/how-to-show-just-the-pages-in-a-segment-when-using-biblatex-and-backref-true) to know how to show just the backrefs inside a segment when `[heading=subbibliography]` is used, instead of showing the occurrences in the whole document.

However, if a new `\DeclareListFormat` has to be described, both answers may be merged.

Comment: The question is interesting, but the aim is wrong, in my opinion: what's the point in knowing that something is cited in chapter 1, which surely is several pages long? I'm mildly against back references, to be honest, but I can understand pointing at a page, not at a bunch of pages.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain myself well. I'm not considering to point to a bunch of pages, but the exact point where the same reference is printed in a partial bibliography. If no such reference point exists (see exceptions), the page is displayed, as usual. On the other hand, in each chapter (segment) I think there is no need to repeat the chapter number in each page, if all of them belong to the same. What I'm proposing is to have each chapter nearly as a fully independent document, with the only difference that pages in the footer are shown in a `chapter-page` format.

Comment: The point of a bibliography is to make it easy to locate sources. The point of a backref, I think, is to make it easy to find where sources are used. But splitting the list just makes the reader's task harder. First I find it in the global bib, now I go to chapter 2's bib. Find it again. Check the references there. Not what I'm looking for? Back to the global bib (since I'll have forgotten the next chapter by now), find it again. Go to chapter 17's bib. Find it. Check the new list of references. + If I had a global list, I could see which chapter probably discussed a reference most.

Comment: Since both of you agree on that, I'm going to edit the question to ask for the exceptions only, i.e. to group the pages into chapters: `(cit. on chapters 1 (pp. 1, 3), 2; and page i)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very possible that not be the best form, but this works in the form that the questions suggests. The bibentries are *generics*.

The code is comments. Read it, please.

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,10pt,twoside,openright]{report}

\begin{filecontents}{IEEEexample.bib}
@inBook{Wolff1962,
  Title                    = {Philosophia prima sive Ontologia},
  Author                   = {Wolff, Christian von},
  Editor                   = {Jean Ecole},
  Publisher                = {Olms},
  Address                  = {Hildesheim},
  Year                     = {1962},
  Part                     = {Abt. 2: Lateinische Schriften},
  Maintitle                = {Gesammelte Werke},
  Volume                   = {3},
  langid                   = {german}
}

@inBook{other1999,
  Title                    = {The title in english},
  Author                   = {Last, Name},
  Editor                   = {Editor Name},
  Publisher                = {Springer},
  Address                  = {New York},
  Year                     = {1999},
  Part                     = {1},
  Maintitle                = {The Maintitle},
  Volume                   = {3},
}

@techreport{Natarajan2011,
author = {Natarajan, Nagarajan and Singh-Blom, Ulf Martin and Tewari, Ambuj and Woods, John O and Dhillon, Inderjit S and Marcotte, Edward M},
file = {:Users/jwoods/Downloads/Papers/Natarajan2011.pdf:pdf},
journal = {UTCS Technical Report},
title = {{Predicting gene\textendash disease associations using multiple species data.}},
volume = {TR-11-37},
year = {2011},
type = {techreport},
keywords = {Technical Report}}

@phdthesis{thesis000,
author = {Author Name},
title = {Title of the thesis},
type= {phdthesis},
year = {2011}}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic,natbib=true,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@chapter}{\setcounter{page}{1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\DeclareListParser*{\forpageref}{-} %A parser for the newpage X-x X:chapter and x:the real page

\newcounter{cbcrfpg}%        Counter for how many times is cited by chapter
\providetoggle{chorpg}%      True: Chapter part (X). False: Page part (x) (chapter or page)
\providetoggle{ifbrefcchap}% if backref is into currentchapter
\togglefalse{ifbrefcchap}%

\newcounter{lastchap}%       It is used in the whole bibliograpy. save the last chapter. 
\setcounter{lastchap}{0}


\newcommand{\onlycurrentchapter}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{chorpg}%                    %If is chapter part. (X)
    {\ifnumequal{#1}{\value{chapter}}      % if chapter part is equal to current chapter.
      {\toggletrue{ifbrefcchap}%                % True the backref into currentpage
       \togglefalse{chorpg}}%                   % The next part will be page part (x)
      {\togglefalse{ifbrefcchap}}%         % else: False the backref into currentpage
    }
    {\iftoggle{ifbrefcchap}             %If is page part and backref into currentpage
       {\stepcounter{cbcrfpg}%             % +1 counter of how many times is cited by chapter
        \listgadd{\mylistofpages}{#1}}%    % Add the page into a internal list.
       {}}} 

\DeclareListFormat{selectitemsforprint}{%  A format for manage every element of backref list.
\toggletrue{chorpg}%                       This is used for select only the elements into current 
\forpageref{\onlycurrentchapter}{#1}} %    chapter.

\DeclareListFormat{printallitems}{%  A format for manage every element of backref list.
  \toggletrue{chorpg}%            %  This is used to classify the backref by chapters and print the
  \forpageref{\printallitems}{#1}%%  of the n-1 of total chapters (n).
}

\newcommand{\printallitems}[1]{%
  \iftoggle{chorpg}%                                         %If chapter part (X)    
     {\ifnumequal{\value{lastchap}}{#1}%                       %If the last chapter is equal to current chapter **
         {}%                                                      %nothing
         {\ifnumequal{\value{cbcrfpg}}{0}                      %if the last chapter is different to current chapter and
             {}                                                     % if counter is zero: Nothing
             {\printtext{\addspace\thelastchap\addspace}%           % if different to zero: Prints!! 1. The chapter numbers
              \usebibmacro{printitems}{parens}{pages}{page}%                             % And the items: it means page of the backref.
              \setcounter{cbcrfpg}{0}\undef{\mylistofpages}}%       % And restart the list of pages and counter
         }%seimprimen
      \setcounter{lastchap}{#1}%                               %Save the last chapter**
     }
     {\stepcounter{cbcrfpg}\listgadd{\mylistofpages}{#1}}%     %If is page part: +1 counter and add to list of pages.
      \togglefalse{chorpg}}%

%**(into backref list: exaple [1-1, 1-2] equals chapters)

\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{\iflistundef{pageref}{}                         %The new pageref bibmacro
 {\setcounter{cbcrfpg}{0}\undef{\mylistofpages}\setcounter{lastchap}{0}  % start list of pages, cunters and last chapter
  \printunit{\adddot\space}                                              % Print a dot
  \ifnumequal{\value{refsegment}}{0}                                     % If refsegment is zero, this means global bibliography
     {\printtext[brackets]{\printtext{cite on \chaptername}%             % Print the part: cite on chapter
      \printlist[printallitems][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}%            % Find and Print the backref of all n-1 chapters
      \printtext{\addspace\thelastchap\addspace}%                        % Print the backref of only n chapter***
      \usebibmacro{printitems}{parens}{pages}{page}%                                          %*** (not print fortwo below line)
     }}
     {\printlist[selectitemsforprint]{pageref}                           % If refsegment different to zero, is a internal bibliography
      \usebibmacro{printitems}{brackets}{backrefpages}{backrefpage}}%                 
     }}

\newbibmacro*{printitems}[3]{%
  \printtext[#1]{%                                                        % Print into brackets
  \ifnumgreater{\value{cbcrfpg}}{1}%                                      % If counter greater to 1
    {\bibstring{#2}}                                                            %Print cite #2 bibstring 
    {\bibstring{#3}}                                                      % else: %Print cite #2 bibstring 
  \forlistloop{\printtext\newunit}{\mylistofpages}}}                      %Print the listofpages items.using \printtext{\newunit\thepagepart}


\begin{document}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\thechapter-\arabic{page}}
 \chapter{Introduction}
  \begin{refsegment}
   \cite{Wolff1962} \lipsum[1-10]
    \cite{Wolff1962}
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsegment}

 \chapter{Second chapter}
  \begin{refsegment}
   \cite{Wolff1962}
   \cite{other1999}
   \nocite{Natarajan2011,thesis000}  
  \printbibliography[segment=\therefsegment,heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsegment}


\cleardoublepage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\Roman{page}}
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]

\end{document}
```

**IMAGES**

`page 1-3`.

[image]

`page 2-1`.

[image]

`page I`.

[image]