# Biblatex: Constraining Backref to show in a segment only those pages that belong to that segment

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, back-referencing

My question is literally like a previous one I found (see this [link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/203768/showing-just-the-pages-in-a-segment-when-using-biblatex-and-backref-true)), which – unfortunately does not have an answer.

Here there are the data:

- I use `biblatex`.
- I have two chapters, and every chapter has to have its own bibliography;
- There has to be a final with **global** bibliography;
- The two chapters' bibliographies do (unfortunately) overlap.

If I use the option `backref` along with refsegment all those entries that overlap between the two bibliographies will also have the pages that belong to the other chapter.

*E.g. say the entry \cite{Shakespeare_1600} is in Chapter 1 at page 3 and in Chapter 2 at page 27. By using `backref`, in the bibliography of Chapter 1, there will be the entry "Shakespeare, W. (1600) (pp.3, 27).*

How to constrain backref to provide, for every chapter's bibliography, the reference page that belongs only to that chapter?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help.

[Concerning the MWE, the question linked works fine, since the OP uses exactly the options I would use].

Comment: Maybe there is a "proper" solution, but if not, you might just have to create duplicates of the BibTex records in question - for example, `\cite{Shakespeare1600c2}` in chapter 2,  and `\cite{Shakespeare1600c3}` in chapter 3.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. :) . I will consider it as a last option. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this here. Attention: it needs **two** biber runs: 
   `pdflatex biber pdflatex biber pdflatex ...`

```
\documentclass[a4paper,titlepage,10pt,twoside,openright]{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=ieee-alphabetic,natbib=true,backref=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{IEEEfull.bib}
\addbibresource{IEEEexample.bib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N\g_UF_allcitekeys_seq

\AtEveryBibitem
 {
  \seq_gput_right:Nx\g_UF_allcitekeys_seq{ \thefield{entrykey} }
 }


\NewDocumentCommand\nociteall { }
 {
  \seq_map_function:NN\g_UF_allcitekeys_seq\nocite
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\makeatletter
 %for the backrefs of the main bib:
\let\oriabx@aux@backref\abx@aux@backref
\renewcommand\abx@aux@backref[5]{%
 \oriabx@aux@backref{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}%
 \oriabx@aux@backref{#1}{#2}{0}{#4}{#5}
 }
\makeatother
\begin{document}

 \chapter{Introduction}
  \begin{refsection}
   \cite{IEEEexample:articledualmonths}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsection}

 \chapter{Second chapter}
  \begin{refsection}
   \cite{IEEEexample:articledualmonths}
   \cite{IEEEexample:IEEEwebsite}
   \nocite{IEEEexample:book_typical,IEEEexample:article_typical}
  \printbibliography[heading=subbibliography]
  \end{refsection}

\cleardoublepage
\nociteall
\printbibliography[heading=bibliography]

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: First of all, thanks a lot for your answer. There is a problem: I use TeXWorks on Mac and I don't use Biber. Strictly speaking I kinda learned about Biber today, since – again – today I moved to BibLaTeX, since I just could not find a way to solve the problem with BibTeX. Is there a way I can avoid to use Biber?

Comment: Btw, this is exactly what I was looking for, if not for the fact that I do not know how to implement it. :)

Comment: You wrote that the linked example can be used as MWE and this uses biber. I have no idea if it works with bibtex but I strongly advise to use biber anyway. A lot of things work only with it. It is really not difficult to switch to biber. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: Actually I found out that TeXShop has Biber as a default engine, thus I switched to it to implement your suggestion (I had actually overlooked that the OP used Biber). Thus, I ran as you suggest and the result is with the pages unconstrained. Also, maybe it is relevant, but in both occasions in which I ran Biber, I received a warning. EDIT: I checked the warning, and it is irrelevant (it is about an entry that is not found).

Comment: What do you mean by " unconstrained"? I got a lot of warning by biber as the example bib is not very good, but didn't want to spent time on adjusting the example.

Comment: A question, most probably stupid, the number of runs does depend on the number of independent chapters?

Comment: No, the second biber run is for the main bib.

Comment: With "unconstrained" I just mean that it does not work. I still get The first chapter with all the pages that refer back to the second chapter.

Comment: Last question. Why do you have two `addbibresource`? Is this relevant? *Edit: Btw, I accepted the answer. It does the job. It's my problem if I don't know how to implement it. :)*

Comment: The two bib's were in the example -- next time you should perhaps be less lazy and make your own example then it would fit better for you ;-)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, even if I did not actually do that out of laziness. But again, thanks for your time. :)